# CD Reader don't work appropriately

Tags: cd

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a laptop with a `TSSTcorp CDDVDW SN-208BB (AS01)` DVD-reader. Now, it is reading only DVDs.

I tried to insert a CD but it was read as empty, although the same works if I try with Windows 10.

How can I get it to read CDs?

Comment: Have you tried other CDs? Also insert your CD and right click on its icon in file manager and select properties and see what file manager shows about Contents and Free space.